# Figure settings in Interactive Navigation window

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I assume it should be possible to change the figure setting after plotting (**not** in the code).

By default, the Interactive Navigation has these buttons as explained in below link: https://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html?highlight=interactive%20navigation

However, it is not possible to change graph settings through any of these buttons (e.g. change axis limitations, or change label name, or change title). These options are available in MATLAB so it definitely should be there in Python3. How can I add these features to Interactive Navigation window?

P.S. My matplotlib version is 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

*"These options are available in MATLAB so it definitely should be there in Python3"* There is no indication for that causality being true.

Setting some of the parameters is nonetheless possible when using the Qt backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
```

Then a respective button is available

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great. Is it possible to get the same feature using Tkinter backend?

Comment: No, it's not unfortunately.